# In SQL Server, how can I insert data into a table that has just one column which is of identity type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert

In SQL Server, how can I insert data into a table that has just one column which is of identity type?
Such as insert into the following table **t**.
How can I write the insert statement?

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Great thanks.

Comment: Is the column also auto incremental?

Comment: @Wai Wong - that's what IDENTITY is in SQL Server...

Comment: Can you give some background on the the purpose of this - what are you wanting to achieve? IDENTITY columns are quite restrictive - a regular int with a unique constraint may well suffice, without all the restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a single value

```
INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES
```

Or to insert multiple rows on SQL Server 2008+

```
MERGE INTO t
USING (SELECT TOP 100 *
       FROM master..spt_values) T
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
  DEFAULT VALUES;
```

To insert multiple rows in a single statement on previous versions would require the values to be entered explicitly, e.g. as below.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT t ON

INSERT INTO t
            (id)
SELECT TOP 100  
               (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM   t (TABLOCKX)) + 
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM   master.dbo.spt_values

SET IDENTITY_INSERT t OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue inserting identity values, then use

```
INSERT YourTable DEFAULT VALUES;
```

If you want to insert explicit values then you can write

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON
INSERT INTO YourTable (id) VALUES (5);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:-

```
INSERT INTO t Values(NULL)
```

Comment: "An explicit value for the identity column in table 't' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."